# What is Easiest Way to Change URL Structure of Dynamic PHP Website?

Tags: php, url

I am a SEO guy and always facing this problem, that PHP sites make dynamic URL with IDs. This is not SEO friendly structure—like this `/article.php?id=2987`—and need to be changed like this `/why-to-hire-a-seo-specialist`. Is their any easiest way to change this type of URL structure?

Comment: Need more info: how are the URLs being created currently? If it's through something like Wordpress there are built-in settings to change the URL structure exactly the way you are talking about. If it's custom-built than you just need to look up how to use htaccess for SEO friendly URL structure.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few different methods but there is no single best way - here are a few ideas:-

- If its a new site choose or recommend to the client that they specify a CMS which already supports search engine friendly urls like Wordpress or Joomla.
- Using htaccess with [ReWriteRule](http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/Creating-Search-Engine-Friendly-URLs-using-.htaccess/35738) or [mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028294/htaccess-mod-rewrite-for-search-engine-friendly-urls)
- Using [PHP](http://www.sitepoint.com/search-engine-friendly-urls/)
- Using [ASP.NET/MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148955/creating-search-engine-friendly-urls-in-asp-net-mvc)